# Sending value through URL in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

Here I want to send the value through URL in ColdFusion by using  tag.
I know it in java but new to CF.
 Can anyone please help me on it.

Thanks in Advance,
Swamy.

Comment: How would you do it in JAVA? Helps understanding what you want to do in Coldfusion.

Comment: [`<cfhttp>` is your friend.](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters sent using query parameters `?x=1&y=2` can be read from CF's URL scope. So the parameters in my example would be `#URL.x#` would have a value of 1, and `#URL.y#` would have a value of 2.